# When do we write "we are done"?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

This may seem like a bit of a silly question, but I notice that in some proofs (a remarkable amount), the author writes: "We are done." after completing a proof. Is this the equivalent of writing one of those black boxes to separate the proof from the rest of the educational text?

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent to saying "QED", but it sounds more badass. You can imagine the author in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF5XrOvEjqU) situation.

Comment: if you want to be really cool you state something like "and as we learned in kindergarden this is obviously trivial" or "even a monkey would admit that...." (especially helpful in any exam.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEhUWWS_prc#t=171

Comment: The use of "we are done" cannot be understood apart from a specific context, except as to a general sense (that the proof is finished).  I can think off the top of my head of three loose scenarios in which it strikes me as justifiable.

Comment: Haha ok thanks guys. I was finding myself writing "We are done." after completing a proof and I just wanted to be sure that I wasn't doing something silly.

Comment: I've used quite a few times that "we're done" thing **here** in this site (as opposed to doing it in the university teaching, or doing exams, etc.). It may mean QED, or it may mean (most likely) that what's left to do is for the OP to complete and it's reasonably straightforward/easy/trivial

Comment: *When do we write “we are done”?* - [Glad you asked !](http://www.trilulilu.ro/done-1) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are done $\iff$ $\square$ $\iff$ QED

Answer (score 2):

yes. (need some more characters.....)